# Multiple word in a string C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define STUD 3

struct students {
  char name[30];
  int score;
  int presentNr;
} student[STUD];

void main() {
  for (int i = 1; i <= STUD; i++) {
    printf("Name of the student %d:\n", i);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", student[i].name);

    printf("His score at class: ");
    scanf("%d", &student[i].score);

    printf("Number of presents at class: ");
    scanf("%d", &student[i].presentNr);
  }
  getch();
}
```

Hi guys! 
I want to store in a struct a name of a student and his score at a class.
At the first loop, I can store multiple words in the variable "name" but, at the second loop, it jump over.

Comment: In C arrays use zero-based indexing. Have your loop run from 0 to `< STUD`. As is you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Should `void main() {` be `int main`?

Comment: Don't use scanf() for strings, use fgets() : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Nothing work...

Comment: You loop must be: for (int i = 0; i < STUD; i++) {...}

Comment: i try, but it's the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First: You need to start your loop with zero (`i = 0`), because C arrays are zero-based.

That said, I guess your problem is because the last `scanf()` leaves a line break in the `stdin` buffer. You can try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STUD 3

struct students {
  char name[30];
  int score;
  int presentNr;
} student[STUD];

void clean_stdin(void)
{
  char c;
  do c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < STUD; i++) {

    printf("Name of the student %d:\n", i + 1);
    fgets((char*)&student[i].name, 30, stdin);

    // Remove the line break at the end of the name
    student[i].name[strlen((char*)&student[i].name) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("His score at class: ");
    scanf("%d", &student[i].score);

    printf("Number of presents at class: ");
    scanf("%d", &student[i].presentNr);

    // cleans stdin buffer
    clean_stdin();
  }

  getchar();
}
```

Note: There's a builtin function (`fflush()`) to flush the input buffer, but sometimes, for some reason it does not work, so we use the custom `clean_stdin()` function.

Comment: Now work ! thank you. I think, the problem was solve with you'r function clean_stdin(); thank you again !

Comment: No problem. Just added a line to remove a `\n` at the end of the name.